# Sources for CBD (Central Business Districts) polygons/ layers

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I'm researching layers/ definitions of CBD (Central Business Districts) in different cities worldwide. However, I could only find layers for individual sites, for example [CBD San Antonio](https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/317fbc576d5643718268d8febed2c220/explore).

There is also the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_business_district) with information like [Sydney CBD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sydney_central_business_district#/media/File:City_of_Sydney_1989-2003.png).

Is there a repository containing CBDs? If not, and if I would be able to build such a repository, would it make sense to build it in open street maps using a specific layer/tag?

Note: this question was migrated from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/465344/sources-for-cbd-polygons-layers